# I have a 1980 mobile home thats got all electric in it can i use 125amp meter box and 100amp breaker box if i can't find 200 amps?

Tags: electrical, outdoor

I have a 1980 mobile home that's got all electric utilities in it.

I'm trying to hook a new electric service to my home on my own property that had existing service 11 years ago. We are having to replace the meter and breaker box.  My hubby put up a 125amp meter and 100amp breaker box, but we cannot find a 200a meter anywhere can what we already put up still work?

Can I use 125amp meter box and 100amp breaker  box if I can't find 200 amps?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?   Also, please add punctuation to your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Trying to hook new electric service to my home on my own property that had existing service 11 years ago. We are having  to replace meter and breaker box and hubby put up a meter 125amp and breaker box 100 amp and cannot find 200 meter anywhere can what we already put up still work?

Comment: 200 amp meter bases and main panels are very commonly available, just go to a big box store or electrical supply house.

Comment: Even with all the "covid related supply chain issues" excuses, my local big-box home improvement stores have consistently had more than a dozen panels on their shelves every time I've stopped by.

Comment: I've attempted to edit your comment into the original question. Neither the original question nor your comment were completely clear to me, so _please_ [edit] it again to ensure I haven't misrepresented anything you were trying to ask and to provide additional clarification of what you currently have, what problem you're trying to solve and what your proposed solution is. TBH, I'm not sure if you _had_ service 11 years ago (implying you don't now), or if the changes to the existing service were made 11 years ago or if the equipment was installed but hasn't been used...

Answer (score 3):

It's worse than that.  You need to use a meter pan that is on the power company's approved list, or they will not connect power to it.

And they're not going to hear "I am bad at shopping" as an excuse.

You need to talk to your power company about a deviation, get their approved equipment list, and then broaden your search for suppliers. Hardware stores, electrical supply houses, try *calling around* instead of only using the internet.   Or hire a professional to do the work - they'll be able to source the needed parts.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing is that the meter pan needs to be on the utility list (as Harper described). Depending on the utility/jurisdiction, that might be one from a short list of meter pans (just a meter), a short list of meter mains (meter + outdoor breaker panel) or some of each. You need to find that out first.

The second thing, though this may just be terminology, is that you do *not* normally supply the actual meter. It needs to come from the utility because they control it and they communicate with it and they get it certified as accurate.

The third thing is that in many, not all, areas only an electrician can do this type of work. In many, not all, areas, a homeowner can do *some* work, but generally not actual meter replacement. You need to make sure that is all properly done or you won't get your permit/inspection/utility hookup done until an electrician gets involved (using up the money you saved by not using an electrician in the first place).

While meter pans and meter mains are *very* specific, main panels (or main panel that is technically a subpanel if you have a meter main) are readily available in all sizes, including 200A. That should not be an issue at all - though it was a bit of a problem ~ 1 - 2 years ago in some areas.

Typical service is now 200A. If you get 200A service then normally all key pieces:

- Meter pan or meter main
- Meter (mine actually was 200A for many years even though I had smaller service, now I have 200A everything - and the same "old" meter)
- Main panel

have to be rated 200A. Exception if you have a meter main + "main panel that is really a subpanel" - then your subpanel just has to be large enough to match the breaker in the meter main that feeds it.

The biggest factor is that the first breaker on your property (in meter main or in main panel) has to protect the meter and the wire from the meter to that breaker. So if you have a 125A meter and a 100A panel (meaning: 100A or larger capacity panel with a 100A main breaker) then you need wire between the meter and panel that is code legal for at least 100A.

But start with your utility - you need to get what they approve.